# A Problem in copying a row from a dataframe into another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem in copying a row from a dataframe into another one. Actually, my original dataframe has a Date column which represents the date and time, But when I copy a row from original dataframe the time value just disappears and only the date rimains.

```
file = 'Core Radio_Other Status2019_07_15.xlsx'
filename = path + '\\' + file
station = 'Huawei Core Other'
df = pd.read_excel (filename,sheet_name = station)
df = df.drop(['Circuits_Installed_#_H','Circuits_Available_#_H'], axis=1)
i=2
[enter image description here][1]data = {'ElementID' : [df.ElementID[i]], 'ElementID1' : [df.ElementID1[i]]\
                                      ,'Date' : [df.Date[i]], 'Traffic_Out_T_H' : [df.Traffic_Out_T_H[i]]\
                                      ,'Traffic_Inc_T_H' : [df.Traffic_Inc_T_H[i]],\
                                      'Traffic_Total_T_H' : [df.Traffic_Total_T_H[i]]\
                                      ,'Overflow_Ratio_%_H' : [df.iloc[i,-1]]}
```

[Up:copy, Down:Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJIRd.jpg)

Comment: try `pd.concat` it would be better if you posted an [mcve]